# avoiding if statements on a static boolean for logic decision making

Tags: c++, logic

I have a class whose member itemType is only set once and never modified but it is used in many if-statements to decide which function to call.
Since itemType is only set once is there way to avoid the if statements else where in the class. This will simplify and clean the code and as a bonus will also save the overhead of if checks.
I was thinking about function a pointer taht I can initiatlize in the constructor based on the itemType value.
Is there any alternate and a better way of doing that?

Please note the original class and code base is large and I cant go around creating child classes based on itemtype.

```
enum ItemTypes
{
    ItemTypeA,
    ItemTypeB,
};


class ItemProcessing
{
public:

    //This function is called hundreds of times
    void ProcessOrder(Order* order)
    {
        //This member itemType is set only once in the constructor and never modified again
        //Is there a way to not check it all the time??
        if (itemtype == ItemTypes::ItemTypeA )
        {
            ProcessTypeA(order)
        }
        else if (itemtype == ItemTypes::ItemTypeB )
        {
            ProcessTypeB(order)
        }
    }

    ItemProcessing(ItemTypes itype)
    {
        itemtype = itype; //can  I do something here like setting a function pointer so I dont have to check this property in ProcessOrder() and call the relevant function directly.
    }

private:

    ItemTypes itemtype;
    void ProcessTypeA(Order*);
    void ProcessTypeB(Order*);
};
```

Comment: Have you considered function pointers?

Answer (score 4):

Use an array of function pointers, indexed by `itemtype`, like this:

```
typedef void(*ProcessType_func_t)(Order *);

ProcessType_func_t processType_f[] = {
    ProcessTypeA,
    ProcessTypeB
};
```

Then you can do:

```
void ProcessOrder(Order *order) {
    ProcessType_f[itemtype](order);
}
```

If you have lots of different functions that need to be dispatched like this, you can use a structure.

```
struct {
    ProcessType_func_t processType_f,
    OtherType_func_t otherType_f,
    ...
} dispatchTable[] = {
    { ProcessTypeA, OtherTypeA, ... },
    { ProcessTypeB, OtherTypeB, ... }
};
```

Then you would use it as:

```
dispatchTable[itemtype].processType_f(order);
```

Finally, you could do the fully object-oriented method, by defining new classes:

```
class Processor { // abstract base class
    public:
        virtual void Process(Order *order) = 0;
};

class ProcessorA {
    public: 
        void Process(Order *order) {
            ProcessTypeA(order);
        }
}


class ProcessorB {
    public: 
        void Process(Order *order) {
            ProcessTypeB(order);
        }
}
```

Then you can have a member variable

```
Processor *processor;
```

and you initialize it when you set `itemtype`

```
ItemProcessing(ItemTypes itype)
{
    itemtype = itype;
    if (itemtype == ItemTypeA) {
        processor = new ProcessorA;
    } else {
        processor = new ProcessorB;
    }
}
```

Then you would use it as:

```
processor->Process(order);
```

This is easily expanded to support more functions that need to dispatch on `itemtype` -- they all become methods in the classes.

I hope I got the syntax right, I don't actually do much C++ OO programming myself.

Comment: thats what I Was originally thinking about doing asI mentioned in my original post. I was just wondering if there any other better ways of doing it.

Comment: I've added an object-oriented method

Answer (score 1):

You can consider to use either a couple of *pointers to member methods* or the *state pattern*.
The former solution has probably higher performance, while the latter is more elegant and flexible (at least from my point of view).

For further details on the state pattern, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). This pattern fits well with your problem, even though you have to refactor a bit your classes.
I guess the first suggestion is indeed quite clear and does not require further details.

Answer (score 1):

In c++ pointer to function should be mimic with virtual function and inheritance. (Polymorphism)
Define a virtual class including a pure virtual methods 
`processOrder ( Order* ordre);`
And define subclass for each value of your enum. 
You can use abstract factory pattern to creat those object or either if needed.

I can write the code if wish.